# Как подключить реализацию библиотеки math.h в языке си используя cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, библиотеки

Использую стандарт с11, компилятор Gcc. Подключил заголовочный файл,запустил программу, и компилятор выдал ошибку "неопредленная ссылка на функцию из math.h". Что мне нужно прописать в cmake, чтоб math.h заработала ? Видел такой вариант как `target_link_libraries(project_name m)`
Но он не работает.
Вот мой cmake файл

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(tf_idf_metric_nonthread C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(inc)
add_executable(tf_idf_metric_nonthread src/main.c inc/str.h src/str.c inc/str_mab.h src/str_map.c inc/file_metric.h src/file_metric.c)
```

Comment: а если вот так написать `target_link_libraries(tf_idf_metric_nonthread m)`?

Comment: Ну само собой я изменял на реальное название проекта

Comment: я у себя протестировал и оно отработало правильно. Показывайте полный файл CMakeLists.txt и содержимое файла `build/CMakeFiles/<ваш проект>.dir/link.txt` там как раз будет видно команду линковки.

Comment: Так что же там было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Видел такой вариант как target_link_libraries(project_name m) Но он не
> работает

Как это - не работает?

> Команда *target_link_libraries(...)* предназначена для определения
> подключаемых библиотек к заданной цели или произвольных аргументов
> командной строки, передаваемых компоновщику.

Д. В. ДУБРОВ
СИСТЕМА ПОСТРОЕНИЯ ПРОЕКТОВ CMAKE

Первый параметр макроса - целевой исполняемый файл, второй - подключаемая библиотека.

Answer (score 1):

нужно компилировать программу с опцией `-lm`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]